# How to add the extention .wav in string matching in writing sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
t2: c2-1(int), c2-2(int), c2-3(varchar), c2-4(varchar)  
t7: c7-1(int), c7-2(int), c7-3(int), c7-4(int), c7-5(varchar)
```

Now, values in `c7-5 are like (abc, def, ghi, jkl . . .)`
Now, values in  `c2-3 and c2-4 are like (abc.wav, def.wav, ghi.wav, jkl.wav . . .)`

The question is: How do I write a query in sql to get all the values of `c2-2 from t2` for which `c2-3 or c2-4 is equal to c7-5`?

Basically, How to add the extension (.wav) to match the value in c2-3 and c2-4 ???

Comment: I deeply hope those are not real table and column names, and you've just used that as an (unnecessarily confusing) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats an idea, you can accomodate it according to your requirement.

```
select *
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.c3 = CONCAT(t1,'.wav')
```

Or more specific to your table names

```
select t2.c2-2
from t2, t7
where t2.c2-3 = CONCAT(t7.c7-5,'.wav') OR t2.c2-4 = CONCAT(t7.c7-5,'.wav')
```

I hope it works.